# apt-get broke after trying to install wine

Tags: apt, kali-linux, wine

I'm a new Linux user. I use Kali Linux and tried to install wine via:

```
sudo apt-get install wine winetricks
```

This, however, didn't work as there were some errors. After that, I cannot install, update or do anything apt-get related. Running apt-get  gives this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Running apt-get install -f makes it try to install wine 1.6, but it fails at that. Here is the initial output for this command:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libp11-kit-gnome-keyring wine1.6 wine1.6-i386
Suggested packages:
  dosbox:any winbind
Recommended packages:
  fonts-droid wine-gecko2.21 wine-mono0.0.8
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libp11-kit-gnome-keyring wine1.6 wine1.6-i386
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 283 not upgraded.
20 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/16.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 120 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

I cannot install anything else, as this wine dependency error gets in the way.
Running apt-get clean does nothing on the matter.
How can I solve this? Either by removing wine once and for all or by installing wine nicely, whatever works and doesn't break the system is fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had to remove the dependencies via dpkg -r

The full set of actions were:

```
sudo dpkg -r libwine:i386
sudo dpkg -r kali-linux-full
sudo dpkg -r regripper
sudo dpkg -r sqldict
sudo dpkg -r ollydbg
sudo dpkg -r wine
```

After that, everything went back to normal.